# String.match() for regex \s on chinese string works differently between IE8 and IE9/Chrome/Firefox/…

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, unicode

When I use regex `\s` for matching Chinese Character Blank (　) in IE8, it returns false, which means it is a two-byte character. On the other hand, in IE9 (or higher version of IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.), it returns true, which means 　 is a one-byte character. Actually, it is a two-byte character.

I want to know if there is any difference between IE8's regex engine and the other higher version browsers’ one. What is it?

The code is as follows.

```
function OneByteCharCheck(value) {
    if (value.match(/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9@\;\:\[\]\{\}\|\^\=\/\!\*\`\"\#\$\+\%\&\'\(\)\,\.\<\>\-\_\?\\\s()ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ ｡｢｣､･ｦ~]*)*$/)) {
        return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually it looks like the character you posted is [U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm), which is 3 bytes long in UTF-8.

Comment: Why do you want to tell one-byte characters from the multi-byte ones?

Comment: AFAIK JavaScript regexes work on codepoints rather than bytes for ages, maybe from the very beginning. I don’t know when they were introduced. If you want to match single-byte characters, you should use `[\x00-\x7F]` class.

Comment: What does your code have in common with `\s` mentioned at the beginning of the question? There are multi-byte characters in your character class, e.g. `ｦ`. In what encoding are these characters supposed to be single-byte? What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Palec: JavaScript's API gives us UTF-16/UCS-2 view of the string, so all your comments are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to the poor conformant of IE8 and below to many of the web standards even at the time of its release.

Running my [test page](http://nhahtdh.clanteam.com/regex/SpaceCharClass.html) on [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/60a828b3ebb6b5f9f7daf8491d3fd086b5b0b358) shows that IE8 only manage to match 1 out of 17 characters that are in Unicode [Space Character (Zs)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) Category, while IE9 successfully match all the 17 characters (which includes U+3000). This is most likely due to Microsoft's effort to conform to many of the web standards **from IE9 and above**.

Even in *IE8* (released **March 2009**), its JavaScript engine only managed to match 1 character, probably space (U+0020), which means that it is **not** even *ECMA-262 3rd-edition* compliant (released **Dec 1999**), since the 3rd edition specification explicitly lists out U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE in section *7.2 White Space*. While not all Zs category code points are mapped since the beginning, code points from U+2000 to U+200A, U+00A0 and U+3000 are already mapped in Unicode 2.0 (dated **July 1996**).

#### Solution

As [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371713/string-match-for-regex-s-on-chinese-string-works-differently-between-ie8-and/21377618?noredirect=1#comment32249311_21377618), it is best that you list out all the characters instead of using the short-hand character class notation. This will ensure consistent behavior across browsers old and new.

#### Appendix

This is the source code of my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Zs = ['\u0020', '\u00a0', '\u1680', '\u2000', '\u2001',
            '\u2002', '\u2003', '\u2004', '\u2005', '\u2006',
            '\u2007', '\u2008', '\u2009', '\u200a', '\u202f',
            '\u205f', '\u3000'];

  var count = 0;          
  for (var i = 0; i < Zs.length; i++) {
      count += /^\s$/.test(Zs[i]);
  }

  document.write("<h2>" + count + "/" + Zs.length + " in Unicode Zs category passed the test</h2>")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Windows 7 IE8 screenshot (by browserstack)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l85uj.png)
[Windows 7 IE9 screenshot (by browserstack)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQhA.png)

Comment: +1 in general relying on browsers' support for non-ASCII characters in character classes is unwise. You usually need to include the exact characters you want to match in the group.